# is there anyway i could put this javascript code in head tag?

Tags: javascript

i have few div's in my form which needs to be hidden at first i.e onLoad. the problem is when i put that into `<head>` tag it will try and execute first giving out the error that div has value null, and when i include it below the form it works perfectly. for example

this code works fine given the JS code is placed below.

```
<div class="error" id="name_error"><p>Input Name</p></div>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="input-text" value="Enter Name..."/>

<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('name_error').style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

and when i try placing the JS code above it doesn't work.

is there anyway i could place the JavaScript code in head tag and it should hide the div when the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there anyway i could place the
>   JavaScript code in head tag and it
>   should hide the div when the page
>   loads?

You need to wrap your code in `onload` event:

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('name_error').style.display = 'none';
};
```

This way you won't get undefined error because the `onload` event is triggered when DOM is available along with other page resources.

Comment: The onload event can fire well after the page has rendered so the 'name_error' element would be visible initially.

Comment: possibly, bear in mind onload fires after the page and all external assets (scripts, stylesheets, images) have loaded. That can be a long time to wait to hide something you don't want initially visible :D

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just put it into a load event, like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById('name_error').style.display = 'none';
}, false);
```

Comment: will this work in IE, because i read it somewhere that EventListener will not work in IE?

Comment: this code does not work and gives this error.  uncaught exception: [Exception... "Not enough arguments" nsresult: "0x80570001 (NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/royalvoip/contact.php :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 11" data: no]

Comment: While this won't work in IE, the idea is sound.  You just need to tweak the syntax for IE.  You can read all about it over at MDC: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Here is how it would be written.

```
$(function(){
    $('#name_error').hide();
});
```

Everything inside `$(function(){ });` will execute after the DOM is loaded, similar to `window.onload`, only with cross browser support.

`$('#name_error')` is like a shortcut to `document.getElementById('name_error')` only using css selector syntax.

`.hide();` is a shortcut for setting the `style.display` to `'none'`.

EDIT : non-jQuery window load.

After I posted this answer, I remembered a post by [Dustin Diaz](http://www.dustindiaz.com/) about the smallest DOMReady code. With his code, it would look like this.

```
function r(f){/in/.test(document.readyState)?setTimeout('r('+f+')',9):f()}
r(function(){
    document.getElementById('name_error').style.display = 'none';
});
```

Read more about line 1 at http://www.dustindiaz.com/smallest-domready-ever/

Comment: jQuery for just a load handler is overkill.

Comment: @icktoofay True, but jQuery is likely to be useful elsewhere on the site as well. I added a non-jQuery loader as well if the site is too small to warrant using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something here? Why not just make the initial style 'display:none'? Rather than leaving it to the default and then immediately hiding it.

Comment: Its a good point. Seems like the name_error only makes sense if javascript is enabled. Presumably you display it when client-side validation fails?

Comment: i was missing this. and i did exactly like this. i set it to display:none via css and then using javascript i made it display='block';

Answer (score 1):

Setting the display to none on the window.load event can result in the content being initially visible - giving a flash as it disappears. However, as pointed out you can't change the display of a DOM element before its rendered.

A good approach is to add (or remove) a class on the html element using Javascript (which you can do in the head) and set a css rule that hides your element if the html tag has the class set.

see: [How to detect if browser JavaScript is off and display a notice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140388/how-to-detect-if-browser-javascript-is-off-and-display-a-notice/5140689#5140689) for an example.

Comment: yes.. rightly said.. i noticed it. and then i actually used css to hide the element. this way the content is hidden initially.

Answer (score 1):

There have been quite a few answers with different methods to delay the execution of the script, with some controversies in the comments, so I have written a little [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/_rsp/uLXPK/) to compare what are the real differences of all of those approaches, because they are certainly not equivalent.

For the impatient who don't want to see the demo, here are the most important things to keep in mind choosing the right tool for the job:

#### window.onload = function () { ... };

- it works in all browsers
- it removes all previous handlers
- it fires only after all images are loaded

#### window.addEventListener("load", function () { ... });

- it doesn't work in Internet Explorer
- it fires only after all images are loaded

#### jQuery(document).ready(function () { ... });

- it works in all browsers
- it fires as soon as the DOM is ready

Just for the curious, this is what jQuery is actually doing to make sure that your handlers are fired as soon as the DOM is ready and to work across browsers:

```
// Handle when the DOM is ready
ready: function( wait ) {
    // A third-party is pushing the ready event forwards
    if ( wait === true ) {
        jQuery.readyWait--;
    }

    // Make sure that the DOM is not already loaded
    if ( !jQuery.readyWait || (wait !== true && !jQuery.isReady) ) {
        // Make sure body exists, at least, in case IE gets a little overzealous (ticket #5443).
        if ( !document.body ) {
            return setTimeout( jQuery.ready, 1 );
        }

        // Remember that the DOM is ready
        jQuery.isReady = true;

        // If a normal DOM Ready event fired, decrement, and wait if need be
        if ( wait !== true && --jQuery.readyWait > 0 ) {
            return;
        }

        // If there are functions bound, to execute
        readyList.resolveWith( document, [ jQuery ] );

        // Trigger any bound ready events
        if ( jQuery.fn.trigger ) {
            jQuery( document ).trigger( "ready" ).unbind( "ready" );
        }
    }
},

bindReady: function() {
    if ( readyBound ) {
        return;
    }

    readyBound = true;

    // Catch cases where $(document).ready() is called after the
    // browser event has already occurred.
    if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
        // Handle it asynchronously to allow scripts the opportunity to delay ready
        return setTimeout( jQuery.ready, 1 );
    }

    // Mozilla, Opera and webkit nightlies currently support this event
    if ( document.addEventListener ) {
        // Use the handy event callback
        document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", DOMContentLoaded, false );

        // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
        window.addEventListener( "load", jQuery.ready, false );

    // If IE event model is used
    } else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
        // ensure firing before onload,
        // maybe late but safe also for iframes
        document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", DOMContentLoaded);

        // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
        window.attachEvent( "onload", jQuery.ready );

        // If IE and not a frame
        // continually check to see if the document is ready
        var toplevel = false;

        try {
            toplevel = window.frameElement == null;
        } catch(e) {}

        if ( document.documentElement.doScroll && toplevel ) {
            doScrollCheck();
        }
    }
},
```

I show it as an example that something that seems simple like a document ready handler may actually be quite complicated if you need it to work on all browsers and not hang your scripts if some image or advertisement is loading with a delay.